# Windows Batch Scripting ~ How to MOVE Files to New Folder based on File Date

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, scripting, command

I'm trying to deal with all files within a folder that look like this:

IMG_20161216_202848.jpg

IMG_20161216_203848.jpg

IMG_20161101_102848.jpg

IMG_20161102_112848.jpg

to be moved into a file structure like this:

**December 2016**

-- IMG_20161216_202848.jpg

-- IMG_20161216_203848.jpg

**November 2016**

-- IMG_20161101_102848.jpg

-- IMG_20161102_112848.jpg

As you can see there is a Top Level folder with a Month - Year name and the child contents of the files.  I would prefer the Month and Year for the top level folder be obtained from the File's Last Modified date.  The files need to be extracted recursively but then all placed into a structure like above; no more recursion.  There wont be any file name repeats, if so just overwrite it.

What is the Windows Batch Script commands to achieve the above?

For the record i'm open to a Windows app that can also do this -- i set it up with a few params and it goes about it for all the files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=_" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\IMG_*_*.jpg" '
 ) DO IF "%%c" neq "" (
  SET /a dmonth="(%%b / 100) %% 100"
  SET /a dyear=%%b / 10000
  FOR %%m IN (January February March April May June
   July August September October November December) DO SET /a dmonth-=1&IF !dmonth!==0 (
   ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%m !dyear!" 2>nul
   ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a_%%b_%%c" "%destdir%\%%m !dyear!\"
  )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` as shown to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

This procedure assumes that all filenames that match the `IMG_*_*.jpg` filemask are strictly IMG_*8numerics*_*whatever*.jpg.

Read each source filename and tokenise on `_`. Take the second token in `%%b` divide it by 100 and calculate mod 100 giving month. Divide the date in `%%b` by 10000 giving year. For each monthname, decrement `dmonth` and if `dmonth` becomes zero, then `%%m` will contain the monthname as text so make the directory ignoring error messages and move the file.

---

To suit subdirectory-scan and another filemask (please note that such seemingly minor changes can require a completely different approach)

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=_" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\IMG_*_*.jpg" "%sourcedir%\VID_*_*.mp4" '
 ) DO IF "%%c" neq "" (
  SET /a dmonth="(%%b / 100) %% 100"
  SET /a dyear=%%b / 10000
  FOR %%m IN (January February March April May June
   July August September October November December) DO SET /a dmonth-=1&IF !dmonth!==0 (
   ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%m !dyear!" 2>nul
   ECHO MOVE "%%a_%%b_%%c" "%destdir%\%%m !dyear!\"
  )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

[untested]

Comment: Excellent Stuff!   One other thing, can u make it handle subdirs and also VID_*_*.mp4 (same format as IMG but it starts with VID and ends with mp4).  In the meantime im going to review docs on all the esoteric commands.

Comment: Thanks.  Good stuff!  Was going to ask how to achieve the above based on the last modified date rather than using the file name but this is good enough for my needs.  I will use what you provided and learn from there.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

As you have explicitly allowed a suggestion for a Windows tool to fulfill this task I recommend the program 'FlexibleRenamer' by Naru (http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA014830/english/FlexRena/).

As renaming a file and moving it is basically the same operation you can use this program to find for example all image files in a folder tree, use either parts of their filename or their last access date to construct a new subfolder and move them into that folder. For other files like *.mp3 it can even read and use the MP3 tags.